# Nifty TextRenderer object is null

Tags: jmonkeyengine, nifty-gui

Im new to nifty and Im trying to change text control using nifty in JME application following this [tutorial](https://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php/jme3:advanced:appstatesdemo).

Below is my TextRenderer code:

```
Element element = nifty.getScreen("loadlevel").findElementByName("loadingtext");
TextRenderer textRenderer = element.getRenderer(TextRenderer.class);
textRenderer.setText("loadingText");
```

Below is my nifty GUI code code for loadLevel scene:

```
<screen id="loadlevel" controller = "jmebase.TestLoadingScreen">
        <layer id="loadinglayer" childLayout="center" backgroundColor="#000000">
            <panel id = "loadingpanel" childLayout="vertical" align="center" valign="center" height="32px" width="70%">
                <control name="loadingbar" align="center" valign="center" width="100%" height="100%" />
                <control id="loadingtext" name="label" align="center" 
                         text="                                                  "/>
            </panel>
        </layer>
    </screen>
```

I printed value of for both element and textRenderer. **element is initialised properly** but **textRenderer object is null**. I googled lot and lots of people got this issue but none provided appropriate solution. Anyone know how to fix it. Im really stuck need help.

Comment: A Nifty `Control` is a composition, consisting of multiple basic elements. The loadingtext element is actually not a text element but it has a nested text inside. You should get the Label Control from loadingtext. It has a setText method. Sorry, i'm on my phone. I can elaborate later.

Comment: loadingtext element is label element and doesnt have setText method. so we get the TextRenderer wrapper for it which has setText method. But I dont know why it is null. Please post your elabotared answer.

Comment: For the case of a `Label` my comment was wrong. Because a `Label` only consists of a single text element, the control tag effectively gets replaced by this text element.

Answer (score 1):

`getRenderer` is going to return `null` if the element does not contain the class you're trying to retrieve. In this case, the element doesn't contain a `TextRenderer`, so it returns `null`.

You can avoid the error:

```
Element element = nifty.getScreen("loadlevel").findElementByName("loadingtext");
if(element == null)
    return;

TextRenderer textRenderer = element.getRenderer(TextRenderer.class);
if(textRenderer == null)
    return;

textRenderer.setText("loadingText");
```

To get your expected result of setting the text, you need to ensure the element you're locating is properly configured.

Comment: element is properly initialised but textRenderer is still null. all code is from above tutorial. going through jme forum i found other dev also have same problem. I tried their solutions but it didnt work. Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: Can't say for sure. The textRenderer isn't being initialized. Attach the debugger and step through the code. See where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the tutorial you linked is outdated. I also can't find any reference to Nifty in it.

I'm using Nifty 1.4 and cannot reproduce your problem. I can set the text via `TextRenderer` from the label.

However, you should avoid using renderers directly if you can achieve the same with a `NiftyControl`:

```
Element loadingtext = screen.findElementById("loadingtext");
Label label = loadingtext.getNiftyControl(Label.class);
label.setText("new text");
```

If this doesn't work for you, there might be a problem with your version of Nifty.

Also note: A text element is not the same as a label control. The Nifty manual explains this in detail:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/nifty-gui/files/nifty-gui/1.3.2/nifty-gui-the-manual-1.3.2.pdf/download